# Combine/concatenate two arrays of integers

Tags: java, arrays

I'm new to Java, and I know there are way better ways to concatenate two arrays like using IntStream.concat method, but as I want to learn, I just preferred to do it in this way

I'm trying to concatenate two arrays of integers using below function

```
public static int[] mergeAndOrder(int[] array1, int[] array2) {

    int [] tmp= new int [array1.length+ array2.length];
    int k=array1.length;
    for(int i=0; i<array1.length; i++)
    {
        tmp[i]=array1[i];
    }

    for(int i=0; i< array2.length; i++)
    {
        tmp[k]=array2[i];
        k++;
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

is it correct?

it seems it did not concatenate two arrays of integers

Comment: why do you think "*it did not concatenate two arrays of integers*"? What is the result? What the expected one? (for which input) How you tested?

Comment: You can also use `System.arraycopy()` to copy array contents.

Comment: You should be asking this question on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @WJS The code doesn't work so the question is off-topic on code review.

Comment: The code works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your approach should work.  I wrote a simple test to prove it:

```
@Test
public void test()
{
    int[] a = {1, 2, 3};
    int[] b = {2, 3, 4};

    int[] expected = {1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4};
    int[] actual = mergeAndOrder(a, b);

    log.info(Arrays.toString(a));
    log.info(Arrays.toString(b));
    log.info(Arrays.toString(actual));

    assertThat(actual, is(expected));
}
```

My log statements seem to agree:

```
2023-06-19 13:48:34,953 INFO  [] (main) [1, 2, 3]
2023-06-19 13:48:34,968 INFO  [] (main) [2, 3, 4]
2023-06-19 13:48:34,968 INFO  [] (main) [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4]
```

Like user16320675, I am wondering why you think it did not concatenate the two arrays; it appears to work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is correct.

I tested it with the following code.

```java
int[] array1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int[] array2 = { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
int[] array3 = mergeAndOrder(array1, array2);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array3));
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

You can add more than one variable to your *for-loop*—place *k* here.

```java
for(int i=0, k=array1.length; i< array2.length; i++, k++)
{
    tmp[k]=array2[i];
}
```

It's worth noting that, this typical procedure is usually done using the *[System#arraycopy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,int,java.lang.Object,int,int))* method.

```java
int [] tmp= new int [array1.length+ array2.length];

System.arraycopy(array1, 0, tmp, 0, array1.length);
System.arraycopy(array2, 0, tmp, array1.length, array2.length);
```

And, as a demonstration, here is an example using a single *while-loop*.

```java
public static int[] mergeAndOrder(int[] array1, int[] array2) {

    int [] tmp= new int [array1.length+ array2.length];

    int indexA = 0, indexB = 0;
    boolean exit = false;
    while (!exit) {
        if (indexA < array1.length) tmp[indexA] = array1[indexA++];
        if (indexB < array2.length) tmp[array1.length + indexB] = array2[indexB++];
        if (indexA == array1.length && indexB == array2.length) exit = true;
    }

    return tmp;
}
```